# Parse PyLint output using Python script

Tags: python, pylint

I am trying to write a simple pylint parser that, given a python project, extracts the information on code smells, class names, and scores.

In particular, the script must analyze each python file and generate a data frame with the previously indicated information (code smells, project name, and score).
I wrote the following snippet:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from pylint.lint import Run


def pylint_project(project_name):


    global project_df
    pylint_options = ["--disable=F0010"]
    python_files = [f for f in os.listdir(project_name) if f.endswith('.py')]
    for file in python_files:
        file_path = os.path.join(project_name, file)
        pylint_output = Run([file_path] + pylint_options)
        smell_count = pylint_output.lstrip().split()[1]
        score = pylint_output.split()[-2]
        project_df = pd.DataFrame({
            "project_name": [project_name],
            "smell_count": [smell_count],
            "score": [score]
        })

    return project_df


path = "path/to/analyze"
com = pylint_project(path)
com.to_csv("path/to/save")
```

However, this snippet doesn't work correctly. Indeed, it only prints:

```
********* Module setup
E:\python_projects\machine_learning_projects\alibi\setup.py:17:0: C0301: Line too long (110/100) (line-too-long)
E:\python_projects\machine_learning_projects\alibi\setup.py:1:0: C0114: Missing module docstring (missing-module-docstring)
E:\python_projects\machine_learning_projects\alibi\setup.py:4:0: C0116: Missing function or method docstring (missing-function-docstring)
E:\python_projects\machine_learning_projects\alibi\setup.py:5:48: C0103: Variable name "f" doesn't conform to snake_case naming style (invalid-name)
E:\python_projects\machine_learning_projects\alibi\setup.py:10:0: W0122: Use of exec (exec-used)
E:\python_projects\machine_learning_projects\alibi\setup.py:10:5: R1732: Consider using 'with' for resource-allocating operations (consider-using-with)
E:\python_projects\machine_learning_projects\alibi\setup.py:10:5: W1514: Using open without explicitly specifying an encoding (unspecified-encoding)
E:\python_projects\machine_learning_projects\alibi\setup.py:34:18: E0602: Undefined variable '__version__' (undefined-variable)

------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 0.00/10 (previous run: 0.00/10, +0.00
```

But, without saving the data set, and in addition, it seems that it only analyzes a single file (setup.py)

How can I fix it?

Comment: What output do you actually want in your DataFrame for the given output you posted? Is it only `("E:\python_projects\machine_learning_projects\alibi", 8, 0.0)`? Or should `project_name` rather be `file_name`?

Comment: Pylint has multiple [output formats](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/usage/output.html) (inclusing JSON for example). Isn't it what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script may include more information than you actually want to use, please adapt to your needs. Especially I don't know if you want to have the code smells itself as well, so I just include them in their own DataFrame.

First, notice the use of `glob`, which in contrast to `os.listdir` returns all files recursively in a folder. If you have a virtual environment folder in the project folder you will need to have some condition to avoid running `pylint` on those.

The use of `StringIO` for capturing the output of `pylint` is already pointed out in some other threads, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56081299/how-to-get-report-score-from-pylint-when-run-python-code).

I use the `JSONReporter` to get an easy-to-parse output. For the score value see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39454034/13106245).

Consider using [`tqdm`](https://tqdm.github.io/) with the for-loop.

```py
from pylint.reporters import JSONReporter
from pylint.lint import Run
from glob import glob
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import json
import os


def pylint_project(path):
    pylint_options = ["--disable=F0010"]
    pylint_overview = []
    pylint_results = []
    glob_pattern = os.path.join(path, "**", "*.py")
    for filepath in glob(glob_pattern, recursive=True):
        reporter_buffer = StringIO()
        results = Run([filepath] + pylint_options, reporter=JSONReporter(reporter_buffer), do_exit=False)
        score = results.linter.stats.global_note
        file_results = json.loads(reporter_buffer.getvalue())
        pylint_results.extend(file_results)
        pylint_overview.append({
            "filepath": os.path.realpath(filepath),
            "smell_count": len(file_results),
            "score": score
        })
    return pd.DataFrame(pylint_overview), pd.DataFrame(pylint_results)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    overview, results = pylint_project(".")
    print("### Overview")
    print(overview)
    print("\n### All Results")
    print(results)
```

Output of the script above:

```
### Overview
                    filepath  smell_count     score
0  /path/to/pylint_parser.py            8  6.923077

### All Results
         type         module             obj  line  column  endLine  endColumn              path                      symbol                                            message message-id
0  convention  pylint_parser                    17       0      NaN        NaN  pylint_parser.py               line-too-long                            Line too long (105/100)      C0301
1  convention  pylint_parser                     1       0      NaN        NaN  pylint_parser.py    missing-module-docstring                           Missing module docstring      C0114
2  convention  pylint_parser  pylint_project    10       0     10.0       18.0  pylint_parser.py  missing-function-docstring               Missing function or method docstring      C0116
3     warning  pylint_parser  pylint_project    17       8     17.0       15.0  pylint_parser.py        redefined-outer-name  Redefining name 'results' from outer scope (li...      W0621
4  convention  pylint_parser                     3       0      3.0       21.0  pylint_parser.py          wrong-import-order  standard import "from glob import glob" should...      C0411
5  convention  pylint_parser                     4       0      4.0       23.0  pylint_parser.py          wrong-import-order  standard import "from io import StringIO" shou...      C0411
6  convention  pylint_parser                     6       0      6.0       11.0  pylint_parser.py          wrong-import-order  standard import "import json" should be placed...      C0411
7  convention  pylint_parser                     7       0      7.0        9.0  pylint_parser.py          wrong-import-order  standard import "import os" should be placed b...      C0411
```